# CSS nested flex box height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a row layout with a nested flex container in the second flex item of the root container. I want the nested flex container to be 100% of the *used* height of its parent.

```
<div class="steps root"><!--root container-->
<div class="step one">
    I am very tall. Others should be as high as I am!
</div>
<div class="step two-and-three">
    <div class="steps"><!--nested container-->
        <div class="step two">
            nested child 1. should have 100% vertical height
        </div>
         <div class="step three">
             nested child 2. should have 100% vertical height
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle demonstrating the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZDuE/316/

If I set an explicit height to my nested flex container, then everything works.

How to tell the nested container to automatically fill up vertical space of its container?

Comment: do you not need to set your height against the "steps root" class? is this what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZDuE/318/ ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `display:flex` to `.step.two-and-three` and remove `padding-bottom`

```css
.steps.root {
  width: 700px;
}
.steps.root>.step.one {
  height: 300px;
  /*simulate big content in left column*/
}
.steps {
  display: flex;
}
.step.one {
  flex: 1 1 33%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.step.two-and-three {
  flex: 2 1 66%;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex; /* added */
}
.step.two {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  background-color: green;
}
.step.three {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  background-color: lime;
}
.step.two-and-three>.steps {
  background-color: olive;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps root">
  <!--root container-->
  <div class="step one">I am very tall. Others should be as high as I am!</div>
  <div class="step two-and-three">
    <div class="steps">
      <!--nested container-->
      <div class="step two">nested child 1. should have 100% vertical height</div>
      <div class="step three">nested child 2. should have 100% vertical height</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```